"not" workaround when using Regular Expression in Python
What I want to do is validate user inputs. The criterion is only numeric inputs are allowed, no alpha, no characters like .,/?<> etc.

Say a user inputs 1989, it will print true
But if the user inputs anything other than numeric characters, say 1989a or a1989 etc, even one character will suffice for the function to print false, then ask the user for another input.
I tried something like this:
import re

def ask_number() -> None:
    # prompt positive int inputs
    while True:
        card = input("Number: ")

        # non numeric input
        if re.search("![0-9]", card):
            print("false")
            continue
        
        print("true")
        break

ask_number()

but it prints "true" for some reason.

Then I also tried using findall:
# non numeric input
if re.findall("![0-9]", card):
    print("false")
    continue

same result.

Then I tried the caret:
# non numeric input
if re.findall("^![0-9]", card):
    print("false")
    continue

still to no avail.
It seems like the bang didn't do anything. I, myself haven't quite mastered regular expressions use in Python. Any help would be appreciated.

! is not a thing for regular expressions.  You want [^0-9] instead.

The caret is the correct character, but in the wrong place. What documentation did you find it in? Did it have an example?

Also take advantage of predefined classes. In this case, \D already means "anything that isn't a digit" so if a string matches \D, it's not purely numerical.

@JohnGordon Ah, that's why it's not working... so in my example, what would "![0-9]" mean? Thank you.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans True, I think i missed that when reading the documentation. I'm too sleepy to read the long documentation. Appreciate it!

Like most characters, ! has no special meaning; it simply matches itself.

Note that \D and str.isdigit use the Unicode definition of digit, which includes things like “٨”. [0-9] is usually better. (Alternatively, you can use \D but pass the re.ASCII flag.)

@Ry- I tried to use \D it effectively detects non numeric characters. Why should I pass the re.ASCII flag? Thank you

Did you click the link?

@tripleee Note that the question you linked to is not exactly a duplicate because it specifically asks for string input that can be converted to an integer with the int constructor, which can include characters such as +, - and _. This question is not looking to convert the input to an integer (the variable name card doesn't sound like a number either), but specifically asks for numeric characters, which should not include +, - and _.

@blhsing The duplicate does have one answer which suggests isdigit. I tried to look for other duplicates but couldn't find one with exactly this use case in the question, though several had isdigit answers as well.

I missed the special characters when reading the documentation.
The easiest way is just use the "\D" as stated in comments. Not only "\D", there are more, such as "\W" and "\S". Please refer to the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Instead, what I should do is:
# non numeric input
if re.search("\\D", card):
    print("false")
    continue

Or:
# non numeric input
if re.search(r"\D", card):
    print("false")
    continue

Thank you to all who have contributed to answer my question.

You can use the str.isdigit method instead since it returns True only if all characters in a string are digits:
while True:
    card = input("Number: ")
    if card.isdigit():
        break
    print('Please enter a number.')


This can also be one of many ways to do it. I didn't know you could do this, thank you for your answer!

if re.search("[a-z]", card):
            continue

here with search you are looking for any a-z in the input, if yes, continue
